# How to update existing Excel .xlsx file using Openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, arcpy

I am trying to make this code work, the problem is that in the excel file the  `print (...)` data is not written, I have tried to use `ws.appened (...)` but without results.

```
import arcpy
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/ejemplo/VINCULACION_S.xlsx")
ws =  wb.active
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/ejemplo/VH_Dissolve.shp",
                          fields="COLOR; INTERNO_DE; CLASE_DEMA; COUNT_AREA; SUM_AREA; SUM_LENGTH",
                          sort_fields="COLOR 222; INTERNO_DE A")
# COLOR, INTERNO_DE, CLASE_DEMA, COUNT_AREA, SUM_AREA y SUM_LENGTH.
for row in rows:
    print("Color: {0}, Interno: {1}, Clase:{2}, ContarA: {3}, SumarA: {4}, SumarL: {5}".format(
        row.getValue("COLOR"),
        row.getValue("INTERNO_DE"),
        row.getValue("CLASE_DEMA"),
        row.getValue("COUNT_AREA"),
        row.getValue("SUM_AREA"),
        row.getValue("SUM_LENGTH")))
wb.save('VINCULACION_S.xlsx')
```

I have also tried to locate the results data in the excel file from cell B3: G3 onwards but I can't find it.

Comment: This doesn't look like it changes anything or even interact with the Workbook.

Comment: `print` is a Python builtin function, and has nothing to do with manipulating your Excel file. You need to assign values to the cells, and `openpyxl` offers quite a few way to do that, the most obvious being `c = ws['A1']` and then `c.value = 123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this code as a solution to the post

```
import arcpy
import openpyxl as px

def main():
    wb = px.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Ejemplo\VINCULACION_S.xlsx")
    ws = wb['VINCULACION_SH_NUE']
    in_features = r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Ejemplo\VH_Dissolve.shp"

    row_num = 3
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(
        in_features,
        ["COLOR", "INTERNO_DE", "CLASE_DEMA", "COUNT_AREA", "SUM_AREA", "SUM_LENGTH"],
    ) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            ws.cell(row=row_num, column=2).value = row[0]
            ws.cell(row=row_num, column=3).value = row[1]
            ws.cell(row=row_num, column=4).value = row[2]
            ws.cell(row=row_num, column=6).value = row[3]
            ws.cell(row=row_num, column=7).value = row[4]
            ws.cell(row=row_num, column=8).value = row[5]
            row_num += 1
    wb.save(r"C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\Ejemplo\VINCULACION_S.xlsx")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try deleting the content in the existing sheet. Save and reload it.**

```
import arcpy
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/ejemplo/VINCULACION_S.xlsx")
ws =  wb.active
k = 100     # approximate no of rows in existing sheet
for i in range(k):
    ws.delete_rows(0)
wb.save()
wb = load_workbook("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/ejemplo/VINCULACION_S.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
```